# Why have my images got extra spacing?

Tags: html, css, layout

Can anyone tell me what is causing the space below the images? There seems to be extra padding in the divs with the red border relating to the images. I cant find this spacing in firebug at all.

Baffled.

[alt text http://antony.co.za/so.jpg](http://antony.co.za/so.jpg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, images align their bottom edges with the baseline of the text.  That space you're seeing is the space below the baseline, used by decenders like q, p, y, etc. (The fact that you have no text is irrelevant - space for them is still reserved.)

You can get rid of it like this:

```
img {  /* Or a suitable class, etc. */
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: thanks for letting me know the cause of this - I never really understood baseline etc before.

Answer (score 5):

It'll likely be the vertical alignment - check the computed style to see what it currently is for the images, then try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
img { vertical-align: text-bottom; }
```

See [That mysterious gap under images](http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/gaps/image-gap.php) and [What is Vertical Align](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) for some examples of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Probably padding related, maybe it is the div containing the image? Could probably help if you posted a link, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using vertical-align bottom is one solution that works.

Since you don't appear to be using images inline with text though, the approach I'd take is to make the images block-level elements:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```